# Prevent cursor passing through checkbox in contenteditable

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a **ToDo List**, and I'm using `contenteditable` for this, I added `contenteditable` in my `ul`, becuse I want to make my entire content editable.

What I want is, prevent caret passing through checkbox.
Is there any way to do this?! 
Thank you in advance!

```css
.radio-btn {
 float: left;  
}
li {
 list-style: none;  
}
ul {
  
 padding: 0;
}
.radiobtn {
  display: inline;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <ul class="list" contenteditable="true">
            <li >
              <div class="radiobtn" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" role="checkbox">
                  <input tabindex="3" type="radio" name="demo-radio">
                </div>
                Some paragraph here
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, You can add span and give it focus : 
`pasteHtmlAtCaret('<div class="radiobtn" contenteditable="false" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" role="checkbox"> <input tabindex="3" type="radio" name="demo-radio"></div><span focus="true"></span>')`

See this plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/IIGkKqQvPv7iZ6H73BGG

//Edit :

Try this CSS :

```
li {
 list-style: none;  
 position:relative;
 margin-left:20px;
}

.radiobtn {
  display: inline;
  position:absolute;
  left:-20px;
}
```

With that, the radio is out of the `<li>` tag, and the caret isn't passing through !

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this doesn't seem to work properly. Check my question again, I edited!

Comment: Thanks, but just try put caret to the start of this text, and start writing. Everything gets messed up :(

Comment: Sadly, i havn't any others ideas :/
Maybe you need to do it with an other way : 
you can do it with a simple textfield, and catch "enter" on keyboard to add a new one with jQuery's next() function.

It can be something like `$(this).next('<input type="radio" /><input type="text" />');`

If it's not clear, i can make a plunkr.

Comment: Thank you, I would appreciate if you provide a plunker, cus it is very hard for me to understand!

Comment: Very basic, but you can do something like that : https://jsfiddle.net/8r6j3oed/1/